# Stack Overflow as a "Read-Only" site

Tags: discussion

I've always wondered, will there anytime (theorically) come a time that every single (general) question will have an answer, though posting a question, will always be a duplicate?

As anybody can see, questions from '09-'12 have alot short general questions, with super-quality answers. In contrary, questions from the last few years, are rather newbie 'specific' questions, or unable-to-debug questions. Any "good" question was already asked. (In some sense, this may be the reason the close-attitude has been driven up dramatically, these years.) Are these kind of questions a reason to run this site?

(It's interesting to see, as 1 line questions from years ago, have been upvoted to skyrocking numbers, only because the answer is good. While today questions like this would be closed as "too broad" or so.)

So, will there come a time, when Stack Overflow will no more allow new posts, but be just an information site?

Comment: Do you foresee a day when Everything Known to Man can be found on the Internet?

Comment: The notion that computing will stop evolving in the next 100 years is rather silly.  It is still very primitive and a long, long way off from what my cat can do.

Comment: As long as there is a person writing code, he will find something new to break.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your premise is flawed.

New languages, frameworks and systems are created **all the time**.

Thinking that such innovation will sometime stop is not realistic.

> So, will there come a time, when Stack Overflow will no more allow new posts, but be just an information site?

I don't see that happening.

Comment: And existing languages etc change.

Comment: Just look at the C# 6.0 features list. This will, undoubtedly, raise a significant number of questions. Hell, it's *already* raised many questions and it's not even *fully released* yet.